# c#.net Windows Form Location

Tags: c#, winforms, location

Hi I can't get this working, the form starts up on a different place on the screen every time, what am I doing wrong?  I am setting the location points on form load.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Report_Maintenance
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
            frm1.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            frm1.Left = 500;
            frm1.Top = 500;           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pay attention to the "new": `frm1 != this`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `Form1_Load` method runs, the form has already been created. When you run `Form1 frm1 = new Form1();` this creates another form that will never be displayed (since you never call `frm1.Show()` or `frm1.ShowDialog()`). Instead, use the current form. You can refer to it through the keyword `this`.

Also, do this as soon as possible, i.e. in the constructor, but after the form has been initialized, i.e., right after `InitializeComponent();`. `InitializeComponent` sets all the form properties and creates all the controls you have defined in the form designer.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    this.Left = 500;
    this.Top = 500; 
}
```

Since these members are known automatically inside the class, you can also omit the `this` keyword.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    Left = 500;
    Top = 500; 
}
```

Note, for illustrative purposes only: You can open more than one instance of the same form. This opens 3 instances at different screen positions:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
    frm1.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    frm1.Left = 200 + i * 100;
    frm1.Top = 400 + i * 50;
    frm1.Text = $"This is instance #{i} of Form1"; // Set the form caption.
    frm1.Show();
}
```

See also: [this (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/this)

Comment: Thank you Olivier!